# How to link SDL2 manually in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, sdl-2, cmake-gui

Recently I have started to learn CMake. To practice, I am trying to link SDL2 manually. I know that there is another way around using `find_file` which is easy. But I want to do it myself for practice.

I get an error when I try to link the `libSDL2main.a` file (running the Makefile using cmd mingw32-make)

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable exe0.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibSDL2main
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\exe0.dir\build.make:105: recipe for target 'exe0.exe' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [exe0.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/exe0.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/exe0.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(SDL_Test_Project)
include_directories(include)
add_executable(exe0 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exe0 libSDL2main.a)
```

**Here main.cpp is only a source file. I have put `SDL2.dll` and `libSDL2main.a` into the root of the project directory**. (I used the CMake GUI to generate the Makefile in Windows 10).

Comment: Try `target_link_libraries(exe0 SDL2main SDL2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to link to the SDL2 libraries directly in `target_link_libraries()` (without defining `IMPORTED` targets, or using `find_library()`), use the **full** path to each library. The [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) variable provides the full path to the root directory of the CMake project:

```
target_link_libraries(exe0 PRIVATE 
    mingw32 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libSDL2main.a
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2.dll
)
```

Note, for SLD2, you may also have to add the `mingw32` to this command when using MinGW for compilation.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I still get error saying undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Comment: @Vignesh That is a different error, which has a couple answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11700542/3987854) you may find useful. Perhaps, you can just add `mwindows` to the end of your `target_link_libraries()` call.

Comment: I found solution. mingw32 must be linked first. mingw32 must be added after PRIVATE. You may edit your answer so that other may find helpful

Comment: @Vignesh Ok, I modified the response to reflect your suggestion. Hope this helped!