# Importance of main() parameters

Tags: linker, sdl, linker-errors, program-entry-point, argc

I'm starting out on SDL using CodeBlocks IDE. I got an error **undefined reference to 'SDL_main'**. I researched and found out that you need to have the parameters

```
int argc, char* args[]
```

in the main(). I added those and the code compiled and worked. My question is, how important are the parameters for the linker to be able to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling with int main(void) fails; main(int argc, char \*argv\[\]) succeeds. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673378/compiling-with-int-mainvoid-fails-mainint-argc-char-argv-succeeds-why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main parameters have to be there because SDL defines main internally as ...`...SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[])...` depending on the system and does some initialization.

Just include main parameters, it doesn't matter if you're not using them.

Comment: Oh, it's simple as that.