# SDL on Eclipse issue

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, mingw, sdl

I have installed SDL on Eclipse on Win 7. I have put all the files from the MinGw zip file of SDL2 in the right places (I think). I put the dll in the system folder, the lib in MinGW's lib and the SDL2 folder in include. I added the link to SDL2 and SDL2main and I wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

int main()
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

but i get this error message:

```
18:56:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Graphics ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O3 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o View.o "..\\View.cpp" 
g++ -o Graphics.exe View.o -lglu32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lgomp -lglew32 -lfreeglut -lopengl32 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
e:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

18:56:12 Build Finished (took 830ms)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importance of main() parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674470/importance-of-main-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
         ^ where have all the arguments gone?
```

Try this:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
```

[The `SDL_main` symbol is kinda particular](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27SDL_main.27.22_...):

```
extern C_LINKAGE int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Comment: Thank you, still not working, though. It is giving the same error