# Multiple definition of main Error

Tags: c++, qt

when I compile my project, I get the following error.

> error:Multiple definition of main()
>   what is the problem?

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

myserver server;
server.startserver();

return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is this the only source file? Try looking at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508654/multiple-definition-of-main

Comment: You are compiling the file that contains `main` twice. Stop doing that.

Comment: may be you are having another file that contains a `main`.

Comment: If you are using Qt you should look on your .pro file.

Comment: Thanks a lot . the problem was in .pro ... iam really thankful

Answer (score 5):

That means in your program you have at least two functions named `main`. Search for `main` in your source files and *eliminate* one or more (by renaming/refactoring for example).

**You can have only one function called `main` in a C/C++ program.**