# Difference between void main and int main

Tags: c, program-entry-point

I have seen many programs that has either `int main()` or `void main()`. I know both are used as the starting point of a program. I am just confused of when to use one and avoid another. I would really appreciate if you could explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current ISO standard, it doesn't change anything, use what the other developers you work with expect. (credits to Lundin to remind me of that)

For ANSI C, `int main` means you will end your program with `return 0;` (or other value, 0 is the standard for "everything's fine").

`void main` will allow you to skip that line, [and have some other effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156423/why-dont-we-use-void-in-main), basically, depending on compiler, you may not be able to access argc and argv since the main take 0 arguments.

Although it doesn't do a lot of bad, it's better in my opinion to use `int main`, so you don't have to worry about the side effect. It's also the norm in ANSI C.

Comment: The year 1990 is already here, international standardization! For those who don't program in "ANSI-C" but in _standard C_, it is perfectly fine to skip the return statement inside `int main (void)`. The year 1999 is already here too! New ISO standard. Or well, it was new, 18 years ago...

Answer (score 1):

`int main()` simply returns a result code to the OS after the execution of your code. For example, returning `0` usually means a successful run, and returning anything else means there was probably an error. Other than debugging and maybe bug reporting, there really isn't much use for returning an `int` from the main function. And of course, `void` means that you don't return anything. Good luck!